# Obtaining a refresh token with Node - AdWords

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-api, google-ads-api

I'm trying to use the AdWords API with Node. I found [this](https://github.com/FallenTech/adwords-api) module, which seems to be the one I'm looking for. The problem is the refresh token.

From what I saw, all example code shows that the token is somehow being generated with a dedicated library. I'm not 100% sure how this works though.

I tried looking up some tutorials, and there was one for YouTube API, but the list did not have AdWords in it. The video can be found [here](https://youtu.be/hfWe1gPCnzc).

I tried looking through the code [here](https://github.com/FallenTech/adwords-api/blob/master/services/managedCustomerService.js), but I cannot see any refresh token mention. I don't remember where but I believe this is the service, which is supposed to be generating it.

I also found [this](https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/examples/generate-oauth20-refresh-token) script, but am not sure what `scopes`, `auth_url` and `token_url` are.

To conclude: Does anyone know how to generate/where to get from the refresh token using Node?

Comment: If I remember this right you can use google playground (just google for it) to make the call and get the refresh token for your credentials. Unfortunately, I cannot verify this myself now as I am in PRC.

Comment: That's the one I tried. AdWords is not on the list. Side note - What's PRC?

Comment: You can enter the URL yourself, I remember. The AdWords Endpoint URL. PRC = Peoples Republic of China. I am death certain I did my debugging for Adwords with Playground, and I am 99% certain, I've got my refresh Token there. Edit: Because I did this with PHP and it wasnt working with the SDK...

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 
"enter the URL yourself"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visit https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
See: "Input your own Scopes", enter "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords" in that field. Click Authorize APIs.

Login, enter your Credentials, get the refresh Token. 
Tell other people if this worked for you, thank you.